# How to save XML of absolute layout pragmatically?

Tags: android, xml

I have built application that enable the user to design his/her Business card. I have used absolute layout for the purpose of card designing. Now the problem is that how to enable the user to edit his/her card after saving the card. Do i have to save the XML of absolute layout to edit the card? or Is their any other method.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use **AbsoluteLayout**.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html):

> **This class was deprecated in API level 3.**

Not sure exactly what are your needs, but a better choice would be [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) or a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

If you want to save the result layout, you might need to store all relevant information about the views in the tree and rebuild it once it is needed.

So for example, if you have a TextView in the card that a user added, save the text, color, margins, etc for that TextView. When needed, create a new TextView and restore the data.

Comment: thanks buddy. I know that AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and i dont have to use this but i didn't find any alternative of AbsoluteLayout. I have implement drag and drop feature in card design, e.g, user can drag TextView to any location he want. If drag and drop is possible in RelativeLayout or FrameLayout then I'll use them.

Comment: You can simulate the X,Y position using the top,left margin of the view in both FrameLayout and RelativeLayout.